# Out of date bank draft

Tags: banking

I have a bank draft sent to me at an old address which has just caught up with me.  Having moved three times. It is in US funds from Deutsche Bank New York which cleared US funds for an investment bank in Canada.

It is dated 4/25/2014 what can be done to cash this or is it just fine to deposit?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, however this is a bank draft not a normal check ... I understand a bank draft never expires.  Also draft has never been signed so never deposited.  Any other answers pls comment .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the check is almost 6 years old is likely to cause your bank to reject the deposit. They get concerned that it was already deposited at the bank or even another bank.

You should check with the issuer to make sure that you didn't already deposit it. They may also have issued a replacement check, which you may have deposited. They should keep track of this to balance their books.